# XSockets.NET windows service won't start

Tags: .net-4.0, windows-services, xsockets.net

I cannot get the xsockets.net windows service to work. Currently, I'm using [this source](http://xsockets.net/api/hosting) because I couldn't find a better one

- the solution was built in VS2012Express edition,
- installed it using .NET v4 framework InstallUtil.exe
- When trying to start the service in windows service dialogue it gives a dialogue saying: `"The XSockets.NET service on Local Computer started and then stopped." The Windows event viewer just lists: "The XSockets.NET service entered the stopped state."`

I'm all newbie to .NET and C#, just trying to get websockets to work and going a little crazy on this issue :-)

Any help appreciated.

Comment: I think we need some additional info about what you are doing.
Post it here or send a email to contact at xsockets.net Reglars
Uffe, Team XSockets

Comment: Hello.
Fastest and easiest way to install the service is documented at http://xsockets.net/api/hosting/windows-service
See the video.

Answer (score 0):

If all the XSockets's plugins (dlls ) is in place, and the app.config of your Windows Service is okey, it should not give that kind of error.

At the following repo you find an template, it is maybe that one you are refereeing to?

https://github.com/MagnusThor/XSockets.Windows.Service

Make sure all of the DLL's listed here 'https://github.com/MagnusThor/XSockets.Windows.Service/tree/master/Dependencies'  is referenced in the project that "host" the XSockets.NET ( project that create an Service ) as shown below

```
 protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            new XSockets.Windows.Service.Host.Instance();
        }
```

<-

Hope that this helps!

Magnus

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all of the DLL's (including dependencies) of your project are on this folder C:\Chocolatey\lib\XSockets.Windows.Service.2.5.2\tools

I had the same problem and I solved putting the dependencies in that folder, i.e: EntityFramework.dll...

I hope this help you.